# Php How to get unique file name

Tags: php

I am try to writing PHP code that generate unique file name.

First of all it will check if first given name file **'Vector background'** exits or not in folder .If yes it will add 1 in last so file name will be **'Vector background 1'** so it will check again if yes than ad one i last so new name will be **'Vector background 11'** it will do while it will get unique name.

i try my self

```
$folder='C:\Users\Desktop\file exits\\';
$name='log';

$result=file_exists($folder.$name);
if ($result == "1") {  //// file exits so work start
///// generate name file that not exists in folder
$name=$name.' 1';
$result=file_exists($folder.$name);

if ($result == "1") {
$name=$name.' 1';
$result=file_exists($folder.$name);
}

}
```

well that is my progress it is not smart code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can rewrite the code so that your "naming" algorithm lives inside a loop.

```
$fname = $folder . $name;
while (file_exists($fname)) {
    $fname = $fname . '1';
}
```

However, this code is not very efficient and can potentially make you run into issues. For instance, the filepath can exceed the maximum number of characters allowed by the OS.

---

If what you're trying to achieve is just a unique filename to prevent filename collisions, PHP has a built in function called [**`tempnam`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). It creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to 0600, in the specified directory.

> string **tempnam** ( string $dir, string $prefix )

so your code can be rewritten like this:

```
$fname = tempname($folder, $name);
```

Comment: I suggest a for loop with i++ and use i in the name the name wont become very large than